# How can I execute User Menu commands from my macro in Far Manager?

Tags: macros, far-manager

I have a custom user menu (Farmenu.ini) in my Far Manager version 3.0.5700.0 x64
I would like to assign shortcut key for some of the menu items.

Maybe I am wrong, I think the way is to create a macro, please let me know if there is a better idea.

**Question**

The macro starts with sending key F2, but then I've stuck, because I do not know how to execute a particular item within the menu using keyboard. (except using up/down arrows then Enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of macros is something else in Far Manager, but you can easily assign a hotkey to the menu entries.

To assign the hot key, open the user menu (<kbd>F2</kbd>), choose the entry you want (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd> keys), and edit it using the <kbd>F4</kbd> key). Set the hotkey to a letter or a Fn key.
You can also access the help pages, while editing the user menu, using <kbd>F1</kbd>.

```
   ╔══════════════ Edit user menu ══════════╗
   ║ Hot key:                               ║
   ║ e                                      ║
   ║ Label:                                 ║
   ║ explorer                               ║
   ╟────────────────────────────────────────╢
   ║ Commands:                              ║
   ║ explorer .                             ║
   ║                                        ║
   ║                                        ║
   ║                                        ║
   ╟────────────────────────────────────────╢
   ║             { OK } [ Cancel ]          ║
   ╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

After you set the hotkey you open again the menu with <kbd>F2</kbd>, and execute the commands by pressing the hotkey (e.g. <kbd>e</kbd>).

```
  ╔════════════ [] ════════════╗
  ║  F5  test                  ║
  ║  e   explorer              ║
  ╚═ Edit: Del,Ins,F4,Alt+F4 ══╝
```